# Bootstrap columns not breaking correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My bootstrap columns are breaking so that on sm view port there are two columns on one row and one column on the next. On xs view port each column is stacked on each other.

html:

```
<div class=" row">
    <div class="sandwich-item col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <h2>hello</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sandwich-item col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <h2>hello</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sandwich-item col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <h2>hello</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.sandwich-item{
    border: 2px solid #390000;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
    .sandwich-item h2 {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

small view port:
[image]

extra small viewport

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.sandwich-item {
  border: 2px solid #390000;
}

.sandwich-item h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class=" row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="sandwich-item">
      <h2>hello</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="sandwich-item">
      <h2>hello</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="sandwich-item">
      <h2>hello</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your `margin-right: 10px;` is breaking the columns.

Comment: thank you that worked ( I will accept the answer in 6 min when it lets me).  Do you know an alternative to margin-right 10 that will leave space between the columns?

Comment: Apply a container inside the column with margin right :) see updated answer

Comment: @Will updated answer is ready, please upvote if you find this helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

> **NOTE: No Need To Give `margin-right: 10px;`**

```css
.sandwich-item{
    border: 2px solid #390000;
}

.sandwich-item h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
       font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <span class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="sandwich-item">
        <h2>hello</h2>
    </div>
 </span>
     
    <span class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="sandwich-item">
        <h2>hello</h2>
    </div>
 </span>
    
    <span class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="sandwich-item">
        <h2>hello</h2>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding the margin for bootstrap's columns. Avoid mixing those classes with any custom styles (borders will mess with the width in some browsers, too); instead, nest your custom styles inside the columns:

```css
.sandwich-item{
    border: 2px solid #390000;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.sandwich-item h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class=" row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
      <div class="sandwich-item">
        <h2>hello</h2>      
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
      <div class="sandwich-item">
        <h2>hello</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
      <div class="sandwich-item">
        <h2>hello</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sandwich-item{
    border: 2px solid #390000; 
}
    .sandwich-item h2 {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<div class=" row">
    <div class="sandwich-item col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <h2>hello</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sandwich-item col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <h2>hello</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sandwich-item col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <h2>hello</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked twice on Chrome and mozila browser but it's not breaking.
You just need to perform a proper browser refresh.
Your code has no error, no need to remove the margin-right: 10px;

Either you put this code or not it's not going to affect anyway.

Comment: This is incorrect, if you resize down to mobile the columns should be spanning across one row with 3 sections. The margin right pushed the columns therefore breaking this.